# How is the '===' operator used in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

taken from http://jsfiddle.net/7huEr/220/

I don't understand the line

```
return $.trim(this.value) === "";
```

I'm guessing it's returning all the input fields whose val are empty...but can someone explain how `.trim` and `===` work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically its returning the boolean true or false.  it returns true if the value is completely empty, or contains white space only.    it returns false otherwise.

Comment: are `==' and `===` interchangeable?

Comment: == is loosely equal === is strictly equal

Comment: === checks the type. In this it means, an empty string. == does not make a type check.

Comment: no.  === is type cast evaluator as well, while == does not check the type (float, int, str, etc)

Comment: @KimGysen: They both check the types. It's what they do with that type information that may cause them to behave differently.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) trims whitespaces from a string. So when you compare resulting string with `""` for *exact match* (type and value) you check for empty input.

Note that unlike `==` which can compare `"1"` and `1`, `===` verifies both value and type match. So it generally preferred to use `===` when type of result is known.

Answer (score 1):

The `$.trim()` function removes all newlines, spaces (including non-breaking spaces), and tabs from the beginning and end of the supplied string. If these whitespace characters occur in the middle of the string, they are preserved.

In your Example, It returns **True** if the Value is `null`.

Incase if the user entered many spaces without any other characters it will return `True`